# image upload result name issue

Tags: php, image, upload

Hello all i have an upload script to upload images to an image folder however the uploaded images look like this:

5353ee0e7ef05_13

and

5353ee0e7f08c_13seatplan

the names should be 13 and 13seatplan, is there a way to fix this? code bellow:

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $f => $name) {
 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $name);
    $extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"][$f] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$f] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$f] > 0)
  {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$f] . "<br>";
  }
  else
  {

    if (file_exists("images/" . $name))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$f], "images/" . uniqid() . "_" . $name);
    }
  }
}
else
{
    $error =  "Invalid file";
}
}
```

I think its an issue with the naming when uploading but i cant figure out the problem, thanks

Comment: Also there is [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) which might help you to spare some `||` with the `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Ah i figure it out, it was an issue with the uniqid()